# grouping the array object in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays:

```
const array1 = [
  {
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Nine',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'One',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'Two',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Eleven',  
  }, 
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'Three',  
  },
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'Four',
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Five',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Twelve',
  },  
  {
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Six',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Seven',  
  },
  {
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Ten',
  }, 
  {
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Eight',
  },
];
```

third expected array:

```
[ 
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'One' },
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'Two' },
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'Three' },
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'Four' },
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Eight' }
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Five' },
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Six' },
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Seven' }
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Twelve' },
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Eleven' },
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Ten' },
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Nine' },
   ]
```

Not sure we could do by shorting in the object and is the best way..

I am trying to make the group of same object value after merging both the array.

what is the best way to implement using javascript?

this is what i tried:

```
let mergeArray = array1.concat(array2);
console.log(mergeArray)

let groups = {};


  for( var i= 0; i< mergeArray.length; i++){
    var groupName = mergeArray[i].group;
    var key = Object.values(mergeArray);
    if(!groups[groupName]){
      groups[groupName] = [];
    }
    groups[groupName].push(mergeArray[i].pageNum, key);

  }

mergeArray = [];

for(let groupName in groups){
//   console.log("FRR",groups);
  mergeArray.push({ pageNum: groups[groupName]})
}

console.log(mergeArray)
```

I have tried with prototype.reduce() function as well. please give me the best possible way.

Comment: show your attempt so far please.  Plus, it's a little unclear what you are attempting to do.  "make group of same object value".  showing your attempt might add clarity to your question.

Comment: Please, add a third array to your post with a sketch of how the outcome is supposed to look like.

Comment: result array = [ 
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'One' },
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'Two' },
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'Three' },
  { pageNum: 1, name: 'Four' },
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Eight' }
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Five' },
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Six' },
  { pageNum: 2, name: 'Seven' }
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Twelve' },
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Eleven' },
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Ten' },
  { pageNum: 3, name: 'Nine' },
   ]

Comment: That's not a group, that's just sorting

Comment: if all you are looking for is sorting then: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp

Comment: it appears that the value of `name` is irrelevant to the sorting, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that simple `sort` is the solution to your question.

```js
const array1 = [{
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Nine',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'One',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'Two',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Eleven',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'Three',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 1,
    name: 'Four',
  },
];

const array2 = [{
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Five',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Twelve',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Six',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Seven',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 3,
    name: 'Ten',
  },
  {
    pageNum: 2,
    name: 'Eight',
  },
];

let mergeArray = array1.concat(array2);
let results = mergeArray.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.pageNum - b.pageNum;
});
console.log(results);
```